# Intellij seems to be ignoring my JUnit tests in a Scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, junit, sbt

I am attempting to run JUnit tests in a Scala project in Intellij. Although running the tests through sbt outside Intellij seems to work fine, Intellij seems to be ignoring my added library dependencies -- that is, it's telling me that `org.junit.Test` and `org.junit.Assert.*` do not exist.

Here is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "sbt_test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.12"
libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.8" % "test->default"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I assume you are using IntelliJ 14.1 and that you import the project as sbt project. What does IDEA log say *Help->Show Log ...*? Does sbt project refresh execute without errors?

Answer (score 2):

When Intellij starts misbehaving, it often helps to select File > Invalidate Caches / Restart.

After Invalidating Caches & Restarting most issues seem to disappear. You can also try refreshing the SBT Project, and finally, if all else fails delete the .idea folder and reimport the project.