# Why does IDEA ignore my testng test?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, testng

I have written a Test NG test to test the queries in a DAO. Granted, there is some complicated setup as part of the spring framework, but, right now, there's nothing in the test. Here it is:

```
public class PortalUserLocationAssociationDaoImplTest extends BaseDaoTest {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
    }


    @Test
    public void testGetLocationIds() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

and here is the parent class, which just does the setup:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/applicationContext-dao-test.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "jpaTransactionManager")
@Transactional
@TestExecutionListeners( { TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
public abstract class BaseDaoTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    public BaseDaoTest() {
        super();
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following results:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:65138,suspend=y,server=n -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:C:\Users\thehl\.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\captureAgent\debugger-agent.jar=file:/C:/Users/thehl/AppData/Local/Temp/capture.props -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\plugins\testng\lib\testng-plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\casenet\Sources\trucare\libs\com\casenet\trucare\lite-model\target\test-classes;C:\casenet\Sources\trucare\libs\com\casenet\trucare\lite-model\target\classes;C:\casenet\Sources\trucare\libs\com\casenet\trucare\core\casenet-domain-model\target\classes;C:\m2repo\com\casenet\tools\casenet-annotation-processing\1.0\casenet-annotation-processing-1.0.jar;C:\casenet\Sources\trucare\libs\com\casenet\eventing\eventing-api\target\classes;C:\m2repo\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.4\jackson-annotations-2.9.4.jar;C:\m2repo\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.2.2.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\m2repo\joda-time\joda-time\2.7\joda-time-2.7.jar;C:\m2repo\org\joda\joda-convert\1.5\joda-convert-1.5.jar;C:\m2repo\org\jadira\usertype\usertype.core\3.1.0.CN10\usertype.core-3.1.0.CN10.jar;C:\m2repo\org\jadira\usertype\usertype.spi\3.1.0.CR10\usertype.spi-3.1.0.CR10.jar;C:\m2repo\org\graniteds\granite-core\3.0.0.M2\granite-core-3.0.0.M2.jar;C:\m2repo\org\jbpm\jbpm3\jbpm-jpdl\3.3.1.CN\jbpm-jpdl-3.3.1.CN.jar;C:\m2repo\cglib\cglib\2.1_3\cglib-2.1_3.jar;C:\m2repo\asm\asm\1.5.3\asm-1.5.3.jar;C:\m2repo\bsh\bsh\1.3.0\bsh-1.3.0.jar;C:\m2repo\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\m2repo\junit\junit\4.8.1\junit-4.8.1.jar;C:\m2repo\org\apache\ant\ant\1.7.0\ant-1.7.0.jar;C:\m2repo\org\apache\ant\ant-launcher\1.7.0\ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar;C:\m2repo\org\apache\jackrabbit\jackrabbit-core\1.4.5\jackrabbit-core-1.4.5.jar;C:\m2repo\concurrent\concurrent\1.3.4\concurrent-1.3.4.jar;C:\m2repo\org\apache\jackrabbit\jackrabbit-api\1.4\jackrabbit-api-1.4.jar;C:\m2repo\org\apache\jackrabbit\jackrabbit-jcr-commons\1.4\jackrabbit-jcr-commons-1.4.jar;C:\m2repo\org\apache\jackrabbit\jackrabbit-spi-commons\1.4\jackrabbit-spi-commons-1.4.jar;C:\m2repo\org\apache\jackrabbit\jackrabbit-spi\1.4\jackrabbit-spi-1.4.jar;C:\m2repo\org\apache\jackrabbit\jackrabbit-text-extractors\1.4\jackrabbit-text-extractors-1.4.jar;C:\m2repo\poi\poi\2.5.1-final-20040804\poi-2.5.1-final-20040804.jar;C:\m2repo\pdfbox\pdfbox\0.6.4\pdfbox-0.6.4.jar;C:\m2repo\org\textmining\tm-extractors\0.4\tm-extractors-0.4.jar;C:\m2repo\nekohtml\nekohtml\0.9.4\nekohtml-0.9.4.jar;C:\m2repo\xerces\xercesImpl\2.8.1\xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar;C:\m2repo\org\apache\lucene\lucene-core\2.2.0\lucene-core-2.2.0.jar;C:\m2repo\org\apache\derby\derby\10.2.1.6\derby-10.2.1.6.jar;C:\m2repo\org\javassist\javassist\3.21.0-GA\javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar;C:\m2repo\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\4.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar;C:\m2repo\javax\validation\validation-api\1.0.0.GA\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar;C:\casenet\Sources\trucare\libs\com\casenet\framework\test\casenet-bean-unit\target\classes;C:\m2repo\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.1\commons-collections-3.1.jar;C:\casenet\Sources\trucare\libs\com\casenet\persistence\casenet-persistence-common\target\classes;C:\m2repo\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\4.1.6.Final\hibernate-core-4.1.6.Final.jar;C:\m2repo\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\m2repo\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.1.3.GA\jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar;C:\m2repo\org\jboss\spec\javax\transaction\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.0.Final\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\m2repo\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\4.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar;C:\m2repo\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\4.1.6.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.6.Final.jar;C:\m2repo\org\testng\testng\6.1.1\testng-6.1.1.jar;C:\m2repo\org\beanshell\bsh\2.0b4\bsh-2.0b4.jar;C:\m2repo\com\beust\jcommander\1.12\jcommander-1.12.jar;C:\m2repo\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.6\snakeyaml-1.6.jar;C:\m2repo\Aspose\Words.jdk16\15.5.0\Words.jdk16-15.5.0.jar;C:\m2repo\Aspose\casenet-Aspose.Words.lic\15.5.0\casenet-Aspose.Words.lic-15.5.0.jar;C:\casenet\Sources\trucare\libs\com\casenet\common\lang\casenet-common-lang\target\classes;C:\m2repo\com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar;C:\m2repo\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.2.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\m2repo\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar;C:\m2repo\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.7\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\m2repo\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.7\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar;C:\m2repo\findbugs\annotations\1.0.0\annotations-1.0.0.jar;C:\m2repo\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\m2repo\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\m2repo\com\lowagie\itext\2.1.0\itext-2.1.0.jar;C:\m2repo\bouncycastle\bcmail-jdk14\136\bcmail-jdk14-136.jar;C:\m2repo\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk14\136\bcprov-jdk14-136.jar;C:\m2repo\org\springframework\spring-core\4.2.2.RELEASE\spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\m2repo\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\m2repo\org\springframework\spring-context\4.2.2.RELEASE\spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\m2repo\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.2.2.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\m2repo\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\m2repo\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.2.2.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\m2repo\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar;C:\m2repo\org\springframework\spring-test\4.2.2.RELEASE\spring-test-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1\plugins\testng\lib\jcommander.jar" org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter -usedefaultlisteners false -socket65137 @w@C:\Users\thehl\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_working_dirs_testng.tmp -temp C:\Users\thehl\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_testng.tmp
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:65138', transport: 'socket'
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\thehl\.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\temp-testng-customsuite.xml

Test ignored.
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:65138', transport: 'socket'

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 2
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried to invalidate and restarted as per: [Intellij seems to be ignoring my JUnit tests in a Scala project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706852/intellij-seems-to-be-ignoring-my-junit-tests-in-a-scala-project)

and then I added the logging request from: https://groups.google.com/a/illuminatedcloud.com/forum/#!topic/discussion/tzWsYki9NBU but it didn't add anything.

Before, when I've run into this, It was because something flipped my src/test/java directory to not be the unit test directory, but this is not the case here. I tried unmarking and then remarking it just to see if something got corrupted.

My XML file is here:

[image]

Contents of applicationContext-dao-test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath*:/entitymanager-test.xml"/>

    <!--    <import resource="classpath*:/core-impl-context.xml" />-->
    <!--<import resource="classpath*:/configurability-impl-context.xml" />-->

    <bean id="portalUserLocationAssociationDao" class="xxx.yyy.zzz.PortalUserLocationAssociationDaoImpl"/>

</beans>
```

Can't think of anything else to try.

Comment: Did you try to change the path of configuration as shown in the answer?

Comment: @nick318 Yes, sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: thanks, please also add what is inside applicationContext-dao-test.xml

Comment: try to look at run configuration inside IDEA, because your output contains following:

  C:\Users\thehl\.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\temp-testng-customsuite.xml

So, temp-testng-customsuite.xml it is not what you are going to run

Comment: and still about path...As shown in your picture, your configuration has following path: "src/test/resources/applicationContext-dao-test.xml" and you try to start it with path "/applicationContext-dao-test.xml", see the difference?

Comment: @nick318 Had a look at that file and it just runs the one test.

Comment: @nick318 starting with a slash will look at the root of all paths on the classpath. Remember that this unit test ran in another module before I moved it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have problem with **context configuration**

Try to change path of configuration like this: `"classpath:applicationContext-dao-test.xml"`
and place that xml in the **root** directory of project.

See: https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-spring-integration-example/

Comment: I added an image with the location to my question. There are modules in modules, so I'm not sure what the root of the project means. I tried changing the xml file to bob.xml and so it made no change. That tends to indicate that the location of the XML is not part of the problem.

Comment: have you tried "classpath:applicationContext-dao-test.xml"?